# Problema con While

Tags: c++

soy nuevo en el lenguaje C++ y tengo un problema con este ciclo.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int iterador=0;
    while (iterador<=10){
        cout<<iterador<<endl;
        iterador+=1;

    cout<<"si";

    }
}
```

Se supone que imprime los números del 0 hasta el 10 y luego imprime algo(yo puse "si" para despistar) pero al ejecutarlo el me lo imprime de la siguiente forma:

```
0
si1
si2
si3
si4
si5
si6
si7
si8
si9
si1
si
```

y lo que quería era esto!

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
si
```

Alguien me puede explicar porque C++ hace esto, porque lo hace así o como funciona C++ con los ciclos?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todo lo que vaya dentro de tu while se va a ejecutar en cada ciclo, intenta sacar  cout<<"si"; del while

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int iterador=0;
 while (iterador<=10){
    cout<<iterador<<endl;
    iterador+=1;

  }
    cout<<"si";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Es lo que dice Jesus. Te animo a que pruebes a hacer lo siguiente:

`for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) cout << i << endl;
  cout << "Si" << endl;`

Es como un while pero con menos lineas de codigo. Lo que viene a hacer es mientra que el iterador que ha sido definidio a 0 sea menor o igual al numero que marco, aumenta la i y por cad aumento haz lo que te indico. En este caso, sacar por pantalla el numero de iteracion.